# Degrees freedom reported by the lmer model don't seem plausible

Tags: r, statistical-significance, lme4-nlme, degrees-of-freedom

I have some problems with respect to the degrees of freedom of my `lmer` model.

This is the output:

```
lmF3<-lmer(var ~ cond  + (1|subj) + (1|blocks) , data=data)


                Estimate Std. Error     df     t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     -0.12844    0.04238    2.30000  -3.031   0.0794 .  
B                0.28143    0.04584 1002.20000   6.139 1.19e-09 ***
```

I've an unbalanced design, a total 1000 obs, 200 in condition A, 800 in condition B.

I've some doubts about the df of the model... in particular about the df of the intercept (2.3), but even of the constrast A vs B (1002.2).

I think there are some problems... but I dunno precisely what could be.
Are those df plausible, or do you think something went wrong?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: are those df plausible, considering the sample and the unbalanced design?

Comment: So write it in the question, and specially allude to it in the title of the question.

Comment: Please show the command(s) you gave to `lmer` (and possibly also to `lmerTest`; as I recall, `lmer` does not itself report degrees of freedom). Note that the df reported are approximations; see for example [this R-help thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2015q3/023757.html).

Comment: I edited the post, and I wrote the command. Thanks

Comment: Can you specify *why* these df values are not plausible?

Comment: Note that for t-value of 6.1, you really don't care about dfs. It's very significant for *any* number of degrees of freedom.

Comment: I wouldn't mind following this up (but OP hasn't been seen here since July ...) the most important information would be the number of blocks, the number of subjects, and the way that the treatments A/B are distributed across blocks and subjects ...

Comment: @amoeba the OP could be worried that the t-value of 6.1 is too large because the wrong values are being used for df.

Answer (score 6):

Are you using the lmerTest package to get your p-values to output for the summary of an lmer object? If so, you are estimating degrees of freedom using the Satterthwaite approximation. The top of your output should say something like:

```
t-tests use  Satterthwaite approximations to degrees of freedom
```

I assume you are asking if these dfs are plausible because they are not integers—they have decimals? Since there is no straightforward way of calculating dfs for these multilevel models, different approximations are used, which gives you the dfs that aren't necessarily integers.

Answer (score 4):

How do you define "plausible" degrees of freedom?

Simply speaking, calculating degrees of freedom for GLMMs is complicated and there is no simple formula for calculating them. Let me quote the *r-sig-mixed-models FAQ*:

> (There is an [R FAQ entry](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-are-p_002dvalues-not-displayed-when-using-lmer_0028_0029_003f) on this topic, which links to a [mailing list
>   post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-May/094765.html) by Doug Bates (there is also a voluminous mailing list thread
>   reproduced on the R wiki). The bottom line is
>
> - In general it is not clear that the null distribution of the computed ratio of sums of squares is really an F distribution, for any
>     choice of denominator degrees of freedom. While this is true for
>     special cases that correspond to classical experimental designs
>     (nested, split-plot, randomized block, etc.), it is apparently not
>     true for more complex designs (unbalanced, GLMMs, temporal or spatial
>     correlation, etc.).
> - For each simple degrees-of-freedom recipe that has been suggested (trace of the hat matrix, etc.) there seems to be at least one fairly
>     simple counterexample where the recipe fails badly.
> - Other df approximation schemes that have been suggested (Satterthwaite, Kenward-Roger, etc.) would apparently be fairly hard
>     to implement in lme4/nlme, both because of a difference in notational
>     framework and because naive approaches would be computationally
>     difficult in the case of large data sets. (The Kenward-Roger approach
>     has now been implemented in the pbkrtest package (as KRmodcomp):
>     although it was derived for LMMs, Stroup [29] states on the basis of
>     (unpresented) simulation results that it actually works reasonably
>     well for GLMMs. However, at present the code in KRmodcomp only handles
>     LMMs.)
> - Note that there are several different issues at play in finite-size (small-sample) adjustments, which apply slightly differently to LMMs
>     and GLMMs.
>
>   - When the responses are normally distributed and the design is balanced, nested etc. (i.e. the classical LMM situation), the scaled
>       deviances and differences in deviances are exactly F-distributed and
>       looking at the experimental design (i.e., which treatments vary/are
>       replicated at which levels) tells us what the relevant degrees of
>       freedom are.
>   - When the data are not classical (crossed, unbalanced, R-side effects), we might still guess that the deviances etc. are
>       approximately F-distributed but that we don't know the real degrees of
>       freedom — this is what the Satterthwaite, Kenward-Roger,
>       Fai-Cornelius, etc. approximations are supposed to do.
>   - When the responses are not normally distributed (as in GLMs and GLMMs), and when the scale parameter is not estimated (as in standard
>       Poisson- and binomial-response models), then the deviance differences
>       are only asymptotically F- or chi-square-distributed (i.e. not for our
>       real, finite-size samples). In standard GLM practice, we usually
>       ignore this problem; there is some literature on finite-size
>       corrections for GLMs under the rubrics of "Bartlett corrections" and
>       "higher order asymptotics" (see McCullagh and Nelder, work by
>       Cordeiro, and the cond package on CRAN [which works with GLMs, not
>       GLMMs]), but it's rarely used. (The bias correction/Firth approach
>       implemented in the brglm package attempts to address the problem of
>       finite-size bias, not finite-size non-chi-squaredness of the deviance
>       differences.)
>   - When the scale parameter in a GLM is estimated rather than fixed (as in Gamma or quasi-likelihood models), it is sometimes recommended
>       to use an F test to account for the uncertainty of the scale parameter
>       (e.g. Venables and Ripley recommend anova(…,test="F") for
>       quasi-likelihood models)
>   - Combining these issues, one has to look pretty hard for information on small-sample or finite-size corrections for GLMMs: Feng
>       et al 2004 [14] and Bell and Grunwald 2010 [6] look like good starting
>       points, but it's not at all trivial.
> - Because the primary authors of lme4 are not convinced of the utility of the general approach of testing with reference to an
>     approximate null distribution, and because of the overhead of anyone
>     else digging into the code to enable the relevant functionality (as a
>     patch or an add-on), this situation is unlikely to change in the
>     future.

Comment: The fact is that, I have conducted various indipendent analysis using the same sample and the same unbalanced design and I found that the df change a lot: sometimes the df are identical for the intercept and for the contrast A vs B, sometimes they substantially differ, like in the example I reported. As I have to write type the results of the experiment, I wonder whether it could be the cues of a potential error

Comment: @piravi as stated above, df's for GLMMs are not "reliable" and the general rationale of lme4 authors was not to output them at all because of that. lmer prints them to provide backward compatibility, but this does not make them any better. df's and p-values for GLMMs are complicated and there is no out-of-the box solution for them. If you really need them, then make deeper research on this problem and calculate the values by hand in a way that fitts your specific problem.